# Can any one help in writing a logic in executing the line after the exception line

Tags: java

Can any one help in writing a logic in executing the line after the exception line. In the code I caught the exception but I want to print line ""This will not be printed"" after exception was caught from the same place.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int d, a;
    try { 
    // monitor a block of code.
    d = 0;
    a = 42 / d;

    System.out.println("This will not be printed.");

    } catch (ArithmeticException e) { // catch divide-by-zero error

        System.out.println("Division by zero.");

    }

    System.out.println("After catch statement."); 

  }
}
```

Comment: Why not move it after the catch?

Comment: No you can't do that. Why you want to do that?

Comment: Once an error is thrown, the rest of the block is no longer executed. You'll need to move any subsequent code you'd like executed after the try-catch block.

Comment: That's not the way exceptions work. You can't go back to the try block after the exception is thrown (unless you put the entire try-catch block in some loop).

Comment: Or use nested try-catch blocks, but if the code is like you have it now, it shouldn't be printed.

Comment: yeah ! I know we cant but I want to execute in the sequence even after exception is caught.in simple if my code contains statements 1-6 and up to 3 statements the program got executed and in the 4 statement I had an exception statement and 5 statement contains any statement(print or variable++ )and 6 statement  where I can handle the exception of 4 statement.if exception occurs the statement 4 throws and  6th statement  catches.cant we try to print the code after exception statement (5th statement). i want a  logic code that executes or prints all non-executed code statements with in the try.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool mExceptionOccur = false;
try { 
     // monitor a block of code.
     d = 0;

     a = 42 / d;

     System.out.println("This will not be printed.");


} catch (ArithmeticException e) { // catch divide-by-zero error
    mExceptionOccur = true;
    System.out.println("Division by zero.");

}finally{
    if (mExceptionOccur)
        System.out.println("After catch statement.  Exception Occurred"); 
    else
        System.out.println("After catch statement.  No Exception Occurred"); 
}
```

Use a try-catch-finally statement. The finally part will always be executed irregardless whether an exception is caught or not.

By adding a variable , you can monitor if an exception have been thrown prior to the executing the finally part.

Comment: Thanks !! but I want  logic code that executes or prints all non-executed code statements with in the try block.

Comment: Put System.out.println("This will not be printed."); in finally

Answer (score -4):

what about this:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        int d, a;
        try { 
        // monitor a block of code.

        System.out.println("This will not be printed.");

        d = 0;

        a = 42 / d;




        } catch (ArithmeticException e) { // catch divide-by-zero error

            System.out.println("Division by zero.");

        }

        System.out.println("After catch statement."); 
    }

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to show with this answer? Code dumps with no explanation are not useful.

Comment: funny but I don’t need it.Thanks for trying :)  @Haseeb Anser